# Parse, query to find objects based on frequency

Tags: ios, swift, parse-server

I want to setup a query where I can find the objects that are present the most times in a class.

For example I have a class named shares

when someone shares a post that post id will get added to the shares class on parse.

I want to find which Ids are shared most, for example top 20 most shared items.

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

set your query with `orderByDescending`

```
query.orderByDescending("shareCount")
```

Your query will be like that:

```
let query = PFQuery(className:"YourClassName")
query.limit = 20
query.orderByDescending("shareCount")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {

}
```

Comment: so you mean to add a column called share count, and when it gets shared add one to the current value and then use that ? That could work

Comment: yes then you can filter the query with the shareCount(max to min)

Comment: what if multiple people share an item at the same time or very close in time would it throw off the actual  count

Comment: Increments are atomic in mongodb, so you can safely increment it